# Minimum path to consume

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, brute-force

Assume that there are 150 coupons to be consumed.
There are 3 ways to consume them in each iteration - 15 at a time,1 at a time or exactly half each time.
Obviously,a coupon can only be consumed in whole.
We need to find out the shortest path(# of iterations) for the coupons to run down to 0.
Is brute force the only way out?
Or do we have an algorithm to tackle such a situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved in [Dynamic Programming (DP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) by following the recursive formula:

```
D(x) = INFINITY x < 0
D(0) = 0
D(x) = min{ D(x-1), D(x-15), D(x/2) } + 1
```

In bottom-up DP it will be something like: (pseudo code)

```
D = new int[151]
D[0] = 0
for (int i = 1; i <151; i++) {
   best = min(D[i-1], D[i/2]) //add floor or ceil according to definition of problem to i/2
   if (i >= 15): 
      best = min(best, D[i-15])  
   D[i] = best + 1
}
return D[150]
```

Comment: But will Dp be th most efficient solution - considering the overlap of sub-solutions to be not that frequent.Wouldnt a brute force recursion be comparable?

Comment: @IUnknown Long story short - no, at least for large values of #coupons. Note that invoking both `D(x-k1), D(x-k2)` for any two constants k1,k2 results in exponential behavior. The most known of this is the fibonacci sequence with k1=1, k2=2. You have k1=1,k2=15 - which will give better behavior - but still exponential, without even taking D(x/2) into account.